# how to use some html element tag inside the json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, bootstrap-4

i bind json data to html table using Ajax,js.
In my project i have 4 table headers(S.no,name,year,download link).
first three columns sync and working without error.but,last column i need bootstrap download button with inserted link . how i do this using json?

***exact what i need:***
if i load the page, s.no,name,year,bootstrap download button + inserted link i need.

**html**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="first bg-primary">
        <h2>A R Rahman All Movies</h2>
        <p>Download songs free</p>
    </div>
    <!--  -->
    <table id="personDataTable" class="table table-dark table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Movie Name</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Download Link</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
    <!-- table end -->

    <script>
        $.ajax({
            //url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            url: 'https://10rs.000webhostapp.com/json-data.json',
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
                drawTable(data);
            }
        });

        function drawTable(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                drawRow(data[i]);
            }
        }

        function drawRow(rowData) {
            var row = $("<tr />")
            $("#personDataTable").append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.year + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.link + "</td>"));
        }
    </script>

    <footer class="bg-danger">
        <p>Design and Developed by Rajadurai</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- container end -->
</body>
```

> And this is the output of data

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Roja",
  "year": "1992",
  "link": "<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Gentleman",
  "year": "1993"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Kizhakku Cheemayile",
  "year": "1993"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Pudhiya Mugam",
  "year": "1993"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Thiruda Thiruda",
  "year": "1993"
}
]
```

Comment: can you add the console.log("data") ?

Comment: hi, created a fiddle for you with a working example (next time, please create a fiddle instead of copy&pasting code directly to here).
https://jsfiddle.net/rau8g9f6/

overall, it was working just fine. you just have to wrap jquery code with jquery.ready (https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and remember loading jquery (wasn't shown in the code)

Comment: thanks for your answer next time i'll use fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my complete answer and project running well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>A R Rahman All Movie Songs</h2>
        <p>Download songs free</p>
    </div>
    <!-- header end -->
    <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table id="personDataTable" class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Movie Name</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- table end -->

    <footer class="bg-success">
        <p style="color:#ffffff;">Design and Developed by
            <span style="color:red;background-color:yellow;">Rajadurai</span>
        </p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        //url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        url: 'https://10rs.000webhostapp.com/ar/json-data.json',
        //url: 'json-data.json',
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            drawTable(data);
        }
    });

    function drawTable(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.title + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.year + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td><a href='" + rowData.link + "' class='btn btn-info' role='button' target='_blank'>Download</a></td>"));
}
</script>
```

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Roja",
    "year": "1992"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Gentleman",
    "year": "1993"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Kizhakku Cheemayile",
    "year": "1993"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Pudhiya Mugam",
    "year": "1993"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Thiruda Thiruda",
    "year": "1993"
}]
```

**OUTPUT**

[Click this link to view output](https://10rs.000webhostapp.com/ar/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
row.append($("<td><a href='" + rowData.link + "'><button class='btn'>Go</button></a></td>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify the link in the data by putting just the link or by replacing the double cote (") with simple (')

> 1- if you want to put just the link in your data
>
> // modify your code like this

```
$.ajax({
        //url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        url: 'https://10rs.000webhostapp.com/json-data.json',
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            drawTable(data);
        }
    });

    function drawTable(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.year + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td><a href='" + rowData.link + "' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Link Button</a></td>"));
    }
```

> 2- if you want to replace the double cote (") with simple cote (')
>   leave your code without changing and it will be functional

Comment: i finished my project with your help bro...you are a life saver

Comment: @Rajadurai, you are welcome and you can mark it as the solution :)