# Html,JSON data linked webpage not showing append JSON data in Mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, json, html, css

Recently I got help from stack overflow for my single webpage project,I completed my project 
Here is the link [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586430/4683342)

**OUTPUT**
[Click this link to see my page](http://10rs.000webhostapp.com/ar/)

Now, problem is, it working fine in desktop browsers.but,not working in Mobile browsers (chrome,Firefox,UC mini, inbuilt MI browser,puffin ) tried desktop mode also. i am able to see html not JSON append data.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not getting this error

Comment: Did you test it on the `https` version on the mobile browsers? It doesn't work on `http` version because of missing CORS configuration

Comment: No,I not tested with https

Comment: How to add CORS setting in script

Comment: If I use https it's working